# Trying to find a way to get the field names of class

Tags: c#, class

So I want to be able to get the fields of a class

```
public class Person
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
}
```

So I will to be able to get the public field names from a class, in this case I want a list of strings being {"Id", "Firstname", "Lastname"}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use reflection to get properties or fields of a type:

```
var properties = typeof(Person)
                     .GetProperties()
                     .Select(p => p.Name)
                     .ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you, Works a treat

Answer (score 0):

Reflection is your keyword. Try something like

```
typeof(Person).GetProperties();
```

Then you can iterate over the result and get the names.

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of reflection.

```
var propertiesInfos = typeof(Person).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public |
                                          BindingFlags.Static);
var propertieNames = string.Format("{{0}}",propertiesInfos.Select(prp=>prp.Name));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [nameof(..)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986596.aspx), and do it like this:

```
string nameOfField = nameof(Lastname);
```

Comment: that is assuming he's compiling with roslyn